# MYSQL: How to get a group total repeating in column while keeping the grouping

Tags: mysql

Generated results that look like this:

```
------------------------
|GROUP A|GROUP B|AMOUNT|
------------------------
|   A   |   1   |   5  |
|   A   |   2   |   4  |
|   B   |   1   |   4  |
|   B   |   2   |   2  |
|   B   |   3   |   6  |
|   C   |   1   |   1  |
|   C   |   2   |   4  |
------------------------
```

Looking to sum in a new column the total of GROUP A that repeats along GROUP B:

```
---------------------------------------
|GROUP A|GROUP B|AMOUNT|SUM of GROUP A|
---------------------------------------
|   A   |   1   |   5  |       9      |
|   A   |   2   |   4  |       9      | 
|   B   |   1   |   4  |      12      |
|   B   |   2   |   2  |      12      |
|   B   |   3   |   6  |      12      |
|   C   |   1   |   1  |       5      |
|   C   |   2   |   4  |       5      |
---------------------------------------
```

I'm using several derived and joined tables, so hoping this would be easy enough to calculate within the current SELECT statement or another derived table. Any ideas? Can't add additional rows using WITH ROLLUP modifier.

Comment: you COULD use a corelated subquery, but performance will be crap. In short, don't do this. you're trying to fill in rows with data that won't be available until after the rows have been "destroyed" by the grouping operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, SumOfGroup_A
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT GROUP_A, SUM(AMOUNT) AS SumOfGroup_A
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY GROUP_A
) t2 ON t1.GROUP_A = t2.GROUP_A
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3eb45/1)